# Can "annular" mean both rectangular ring and circular ring?

Tags: word-request, definition

[image: a rectangular box shape next to a ring shape]

Some dictionaries define the term "annular" as ring-shaped.
So, I think both shapes shown above can be described as an annular shape.
If it is necessary to distinguish the two shapes, the left one may be described as a rectangular annular shape while the right one may be described as a circular annular shape.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I am not convinced. Look at the first three definitions in this: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/annulus

Comment: A rectangle is not a ring and is not annular. An annulus is a flat shape like a ring. Its edges are two circles that have the same centre.

Comment: Would you advise me how to express the left shape?

Comment: *rectangular* or *oblong*. I am not aware of a common word that emphasizes the hollowness of the shape.

Comment: A rectangular frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we look at the helpful link to Wiktionary provided by @JavaLatte we see

> 1 A ring- or donut-shaped area or structure.
> 2 (geometry) The region in a plane between two concentric circles of different radii.
> 3 (topology) Any topological space homeomorphic to the region in a plane between two concentric circles of different radius.

The first two suggest that only the circular version can properly be called an annulus but the third indicates that if you are talking to a topologist they regard the two shapes you show as indistinguishable. However topologists are unusual people who also believe that a coffee cup is indistinguishable from a bagel so it would be better to go for the option @KateBunting suggests of *rectangular* frame.